# Loop through query results, execute subquery, and show nested results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SELECT statement that returns a list of invoices from my `Invoice_Info` table:

| Invoice_Number | Date | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 11/10/2023 | 13.92 |
| 222 | 11/14/2023 | 28.96 |

For each record identified in the query above, I need to execute a second SELECT statement retrieving the invoice's line item details from the `Invoice Line Items` table:

| Invoice_Number | Item_Number | Description | Unit_Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 21 | Blue car | 4.95 | 1 |
| 111 | 54 | Red truck | 2.99 | 3 |
| 222 | 14 | Yellow bike | 4.25 | 2 |
| 222 | 54 | Red truck | 2.99 | 4 |
| 222 | 91 | Green van | 8.50 | 1 |

I need the results of both queries presented in a single output showing a row for each invoice, immediately followed by the invoice's line items:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 11/10/2023 | 13.92 |  |
| 21 | Blue car | 4.95 | 1 |
| 54 | Red truck | 2.99 | 3 |
| 222 | 11/14/2023 | 28.96 |  |
| 14 | Yellow bike | 4.25 | 2 |
| 54 | Red truck | 2.99 | 4 |
| 91 | Green van | 8.50 | 1 |

How can I loop through the results of the invoices query, execute my line items query, and generate the desired output (with an emphasis on each invoice line being immediately followed by its line item rows)?

Comment: Why not use a single query and join the invoice lines in? That said SQL is the wrong place to do this as a result set should have the same data type for all values of a column, whereas here you will have to convert to a string. You are trying to solve a presentation problem at the database level instead of the presentation level.

Comment: Please don't add `[SOLVED]` to your title, this site is actually quite clever, given its been build specifically to deal with Q&A over many years, such that when you see a question that has an accepted answer its shows up differently in order to indicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `UNION ALL` operator along with ordering to ensure the line items appear immediately after their respective invoices.

```
;WITH InvoicesAndItems AS (
    SELECT 
        ii.Invoice_Number AS col1,
        ii.Invoice_Number AS col,
        cast(ii.Date as varchar(50)) AS col2,
        ii.Total AS col3,
        NULL AS col4,
        1 AS SortOrder
    FROM Invoice_Info ii
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        ili.Item_Number,
        ili.Invoice_Number,
        ili.Description,
        ili.Unit_Price,
        ili.Quantity,
        2 AS SortOrder
    FROM Invoice_Line_Items ili
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM InvoicesAndItems
ORDER BY col, SortOrder;
```

Comment: Is the CTE necessary?

Comment: Thanks Amit. This helped point me in the right direction. Didn't realize I could simply UNION the ttwo queries, then use two ORDER BY conditions to achieve the desire output. I've got my desired output now.